# How to share sound on Mac from Docker container

Tags: macos, docker, audio, x11

I'm looking for a way to share sound from a Docker container running a GUI app to a MacOS device. Right now I'm only running browsers in a container like chrome, firefox, and tor. I suppose it would be applicable to something like a spotify container as well. I know there are multiple examples online (mostly from Jessie Frazelle's containers) which display sharing sound for Linux machines. But is this possible on MacOS?

Example of what I am running on my Mac which works just fine without audio

```
docker run -it \
           -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
           -e DISPLAY=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '"'"'$1=="inet" {print $2}'"'"'):0 \
           --privileged jess/chrome
```

Example of how most online examples give of how run the container on Linux which shares sound

```
docker run -it \
           -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
           -e DISPLAY=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '"'"'$1=="inet" {print $2}'"'"'):0 \
           --device /dev/snd \ # this is what shares the sound
           --privileged jess/chrome
```

So what would be the equivalent to `--device /dev/snd` for mac? Are there additional configurations or supporting software that I would need to do first? Say like install pulseaudio on the mac, or check off a specific Xquartz config? Has anyone had success with this? Is it even possible? I have not had much success with googling.

MacOS Sierra 10.12.5
Docker 17.12.0
XQuartz 2.7.11